# Copy row from one gridview to another in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview having columns:

FirstName   | LastName   |    Add

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="AuthorID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="gv1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Add" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

When click the add button, copy this row to the second gridview and hide/delete this row from orignal gridview. How to do this?

Comment: Add a new column 'Copy', and get the row info from  gv1_RowCommand if command comes from Copy click. Reload second grid by appending new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://forums.asp.net/p/1297473/2522734.aspx

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-move-selected-record-from-one.html

Take a look on these links. That will help u